# LXC container not connecting to bridge on startup

Tags: linux, lxc, containers

I'm struggling to get an lxc container to startup with proper networking.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lxcbr0
iface lxcbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.5.69
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

container config:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 26:0b:6c:e8:dc:65
lxc.network.flags = up
```

When I boot up the container, networking doesn't work. When I look at the bridge config, the container isn't connected:

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
lxcbr0          8000.509a4c6f57b4       no              eno1
```

If I manually add the container's virtual network device to the bridge, then everything is groovy:

```
#brctl addif lxcbr0 veth0BCEEH
```

These configs are basically from an existing machine with working configurations, so there must be some sort of simple gotcha that I am missing.

How can I get the container to add the veth to the bridge automatically?

In case it matters:

```
 lxc version: 2.0.7
 Linux hostname 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I sort of encountered the same; in my case `/etc/default/lxc` needed updating to contain :

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false"
```